# AJAX Toolkit controls showing errors in designer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there something I need to install to get Ajax Toolkit control support in "design" mode in VS2008?  Also, I seem to be having a problem when adding controls within Ajax controls.  They don't update the designer.cs file.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Ajax toolkit controls seem to have very dodgy drag and drop supported in the designer. If you want to drag and drop controls from the toolbox, try dragging them into your source view.

My suggestion would be to just get accustomed to working in the source, and forgo working with the designer - it tends to be slow and a bit unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

if you get the error in designer mode: "Error Creating Control; Unknown Control 'asp:TabContainer  etc' then the problem is a corrupt Asp.net Temporary Filesystem;

1. Close Visual Studio developer;
2. To correct, go to the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" depending on the framework you are using and delete the contents of this folder.
3. Restart VS. it should work like a charm